# SQLAlchemy one-to-one relationship creates multiple rows

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to make a one-to-one relationship between two tables in my database(postgresql). I'm using SQLAlchemy in python. So, I used an example given in the documentation itself. [one-to-one relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-one)

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, Date, Float
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    child = relationship("Child", uselist=False, back_populates="parent")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="child"

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://testdb:hello@localhost/fullstack')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

This creates two tables parent and child.
Now I insert values in parent table and child table

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from test_databasesetup import Base, Parent, Child

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://testdb:hello@localhost/fullstack')
Base.metadata.bind = engine
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = DBSession()

parent = Parent()
session.add(parent)
session.commit() // insert in 'parent' table with id=1
// insert into child
child = Child(parent_id=1)
session.add(child)
session.commit()

child = Child(parent_id=1)
session.add(child)
session.commit()
```

Inserting child again with the same parent_id should have thrown an error but the record got inserted.

```
id | parent_id 
----+-----------
  1 |         1
  2 |         1
```

What should be done here so that I can only insert one child corresponding to a parent id. I don't want children having the same parent_id.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are specifying the field `parent_id` directly. In this case `sqlalchemy` does not get a chance to validate the relationship to be `one-to-one`. Instead, use the relationship:

```
# add new parent to the database
parent = Parent()
session.add(parent)
session.commit()

# insert new child for this parent
child = Child(parent=parent)  # @note: this is the code change. \
# Here we refer to parent, not parent_id field
session.add(child)
session.commit()

# insert another child for the same parent:
# this will assign this new child to the parent, and will 
# *remove* previous child from this parent
child = Child(parent=parent)
session.add(child)
session.commit()
```

Another side-effect is much cleaner code. Yet another one is the fact that `sqlalchemy` can figure out the foreign keys itself, and you do not need to know the `id` of the object:

```
parent = Parent()
child = Child(parent=parent)
# it is enough to add only one related object, and the other (Child) will be added to session automatically
session.add(parent)
# we can commit only now, when we finished working on all the objects in the current session/transaction
session.commit()
```

---

*In addition, you can add a unique constraint to the `Child.parent_id` field as an additional database level check, which would have thrown an error in your case:*

```
parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'), unique=True)
```